# Forward Engineering MySQL Workbench Error 1064

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, mysql-workbench

I made a EER diagram and I am trying to Forward Engineer it but I get this error and I can't find the mistake.

> Executing SQL script in server ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in
>   your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB
>   server version for the right syntax to use near 'INDEX
>   `fk_User_Wallets1_idx` (`Wallets_idWallets` ASC) VISIBLE, CONSTRAINT '
>   at line 13

SQL Code:

```
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`User` (
          `idUser` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
          `email` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
          `adress` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
          `password` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
          `saldo` INT NULL,
          `date_start` DATETIME NULL,
          `date_end` DATETIME NULL,
          `Rolls_idRolls` INT NOT NULL,
          `Wallets_idWallets` INT NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`idUser`, `Rolls_idRolls`, `Wallets_idWallets`),
          INDEX `fk_User_Rolls1_idx` (`Rolls_idRolls` ASC) VISIBLE,
          INDEX `fk_User_Wallets1_idx` (`Wallets_idWallets` ASC) VISIBLE,
          CONSTRAINT `fk_User_Rolls1`
            FOREIGN KEY (`Rolls_idRolls`)
            REFERENCES `mydb`.`Rolls` (`idRolls`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
          CONSTRAINT `fk_User_Wallets1`
            FOREIGN KEY (`Wallets_idWallets`)
            REFERENCES `mydb`.`Wallets` (`idWallets`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
        ENGINE = InnoDB

SQL script execution finished: statements: 11 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch
```

Comment: Is that end parenthesis meant to be there at the end of the query? `ON UPDATE NO ACTION) ENGINE = InnoDB` It seems like that end part is floating outside of the create statement `ENGINE = InnoDB`.

Comment: You should check that invisible indexes are available in your version of mysql. What version are you on? https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-invisible-indexes/

Comment: (unrelated) This PK seems very strange:  PRIMARY KEY (`idUser`, `Rolls_idRolls`, `Wallets_idWallets`)  -- because `idUser` is logically unique, and `PRIMARY KEY` implies unique -- why have the other columns listed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you add engine

ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

Comment: How does this fix anything?

Answer (score 6):

This is mysql version issue  Remove the VISIBLE.  and run the code manually . Or update mysql server and the client into same version .
 (`Wallets_idWallets` ASC) VISIBLE into (`Wallets_idWallets` ASC)

Answer (score 0):

Before you forward engineering tick the below options and continue the process,

Go to the option section > **Under the set options for Database to be created**

- Skip creation of foreign keys
- Skip creation of Indexes as well
- generate separate create index statements
- Generate Insert statement for table

And continue the forward engineering process.

Comment: Can you explain your solution please? What is the problem and how does your proposed solution solve it?