# MySQL 8.0 workbench errors starting and stopping and options file

Tags: mysql

Workbench 8.0 will not connect properly to the MYSQL root instance running on a clean install of windows 10.

Errors received attempting to start and stop: **"argument 2: <class 'Type Error': wrong type"**

Error received when accessing Options file: **"UnicodeDecodeError:'Charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 4326: Character maps to**

***Solved the options file problem by replacing my.ini with a simplified version. Options file now works and database functions but still cannot start or stop from workbench. Unable to find what was causing the problem in the default my.INI installed by the installer.***

This is only occurring on recent install of Windows 10 and MySQL 8.0. Older versions of Mysql and Windows 10 work fine.
Uninstalled and and reinstalled both mysql and windows with same error repeating.

what happends when attempting to stop server from Workbench:
2021-02-01 19:25:44 - Workbench will use cmd shell commands to start/stop this instance

2021-02-01 19:25:44 - Server is running

2021-02-01 19:25:46 - Could not stop server: argument 2: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type

2021-02-01 19:25:48 - Checking server status...

2021-02-01 19:25:48 - MySQL server is currently running

2021-02-01 19:25:48 - Checking server status...

2021-02-01 19:25:48 - MySQL server is currently running

2021-02-01 19:25:44 - Workbench will use cmd shell commands to start/stop this instance

2021-02-01 19:25:44 - Server is running

2021-02-01 19:25:46 - Could not stop server: argument 2: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type

***The above error is not showing up in the error log (see below) and I am able to stop and start the service via the Window's Service APP where the service is listed as MYSQL 80.***

2021-02-02T03:20:43.902111Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010915] [Server] 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.

2021-02-02T03:20:43.903132Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.23) starting as process 888

2021-02-02T03:20:43.919261Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.

2021-02-02T03:20:44.271604Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.

2021-02-02T03:20:44.411160Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060

2021-02-02T03:20:44.465498Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.

2021-02-02T03:20:44.465982Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.

2021-02-02T03:20:44.491579Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.23'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.

2021-02-02T03:23:46.880575Z 0 [System] [MY-013105] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Normal shutdown.

2021-02-02T03:23:48.065031Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.23)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.

2021-02-02T03:23:50.987730Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010915] [Server] 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.

2021-02-02T03:23:50.988829Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.23) starting as process 7420

2021-02-02T03:23:51.004657Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.

2021-02-02T03:23:51.359656Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.

2021-02-02T03:23:51.504507Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060

2021-02-02T03:23:51.553628Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.

2021-02-02T03:23:51.554141Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.

2021-02-02T03:23:51.579556Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.23'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL

I don't believe this is a bug. I am not a programmer therefore even if it is a bug I would not know what to report. I am guessing that this is operator error. I am missing something, repeatedly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, please provide complete Error traceback.

Comment: This question is more for mysql support. I would raise it on bugs.mysql.com

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52624659/forward-engineering-mysql-workbench-error-1064/52625075#52625075, please glance this link

Answer (score 2):

In the my.ini file sometimes  “ is used instead of " in the comments.
Just replace the “ with normal " and save the my.ini file.
No problems afther this change.

Comment: 2022-08-03: Thanks @Paul. This problem still exists with 8.0.30.0 on Windows. Replacing the 66 & 99 quotes with normal double quotes stop MySQL Workbench throwing a hissy fit when it loads the my.ini file.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with the my.ini file. Make a backup an open it with the Notepad++. Go to the position with the error and change the character... you can see in status bar the line .. and the position ...
In my case i change three characters in line 135. (it is a comment line)
from: # range from 1 to 2^32 − 1. “Unique” means that each ID must be different
to:   # range from 1 to 2^32 - 1. "Unique" means that each ID must be different

Save the file and use it. If give more same errors modify them with the same way.

Comment: It worked for me, thank u :) @ΑΓΡΙΑ

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps I took to resolve my MySQL Workbench 8.0.23 issue
that resulted in an inability to start & stop the MySQL server process (mysqld)
from MySQL Workbench (O/S=Windows only answer)...

1. Close MySQL Workbench
2. In C:\Users<Your account>\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench\serverinstances.xml:

- Replaced:

  - `<value type="string" key="sys.mysqld.start">sc start MySQL80</value>`
  - `<value type="string" key="sys.mysqld.stop">sc stop MySQL80</value>`
- With:

  - `<value type="string" key="sys.mysqld.start">net start MySQL80</value>`
  - `<value type="string" key="sys.mysqld.stop">net stop MySQL80</value>`
- Notes:

  - My mysqld service was installed w/ the name='MySQL80', replace/match this value to your actual service name.
  - My mysqld service was installed using a 'Network Service' account, verify that your service is also running as a network service before using the 'net' commands

3. Setup MySQLWorkbench CE 8.0 executable to 'Run As Administrator' so that the commands to start and stop the service run as an administrator:

- In File Explorer find the MySQLWorkbench.exe executable:
  E.g: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0\MySQLWorkbench.exe
- In File Explorer, Select the exe, Right click the exe, select 'Properties', select
  'Compatibility' tab: specify 'Run This Program As An Administrator'

4. Start MySQL Workbench

- Attempt to start or stop the MySql server process (mysqld)

Notes:

- O/S = Windows 10 specific
- MySQL & MySQL Workbench were installed via the MySQL CE 8.0.23 installer
- Installed MySQL 8.0.23 as an upgrade from 5.7 to 8.0.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this problem for a week now after editing the MySql my.ini file with Windows 10 notepad. After editing it, I was unable to start any database. After replacing the my.ini file with a backup, it worked normally. So, I figured Notepad was adding BOM characters when saving but it was not. I encountered the same problem again using the option file function in MySql Workbench. I got the same error mentioned above. I am not that familiar with dealing with a hex editor or encoding in general but I did notice I could find the offset position using the free Neo hex editor. I know some posters have suggested changing the characters at that location mentioned in the error. But since I didn't know what they meant, my first attempts failed. Then I noticed the corresponding location in the comment section in the my.ini file for the byte in the error offset(9D) was a period. So, I just went to another period in the comment section and copied its byte(0D) and replaced the 9D byte with it. I searched the rest of the file and replaced several other 9D bytes. Saved the file and had no problem afterwards. I'm not sure what is creating the problem but for me, this definitely solved this problem. I read the post from ΑΓΡΙΑ ΠΕΣΤΡΟΦΑ and I believe this is similar if not the same suggestion as his post. Since I am a beginner user and didn't understand exactly what he wanted me to do when I first read it, I tried to be more descriptive here for other beginners. The problem definitely has to do with the characters around the word Unique. Search for that word and change the symbols/bytes around it and that should solve the problem. Hope this helps!